# Почему на выходе искаженное изображение?

Tags: php

Обрабатываю изображение

```
    $pic = imagecreatefromwebp('https://lh4.ggpht.com/XDX7NhI4PEE-4ygOxqZt6wy90kb9b6GY07Rg4-VnohpHzgRS8C8GdaLZAl_GfsyCkaA=h310-rw');
    imagejpeg($pic, './example.jpg', 100);
    imagedestroy($pic);
```

Иногда получается нормальное обработанное изображение, иногда непонятно что http://savepic.ru/7844267.png

**UPD:** обновил код

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, тут дело в альфа канале, или в цветовом профиле.

Если исходное изображение содержит альфа канал, то вам либо нужно заливать фон каким-то цветом (по умолчанию черный), либо сохранять в формате png.

Также входное изображение может содержать цветовые профили.

Вот пример картинки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Google Chrome она показывается нормально, но если вы, например, попробуете ее открыть в paint, то увидите совсем другие цвета.
Библиотека gd не поддерживает цветовые профили, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Спасибо, позже отпишу что получилось

Comment: СОхранение в формате PNG не помагает, так же история

Answer (score 0):

Сказать наверняка нельзя, т.к. исходного файла вы не дали. Но раз вы конвертируете из PNG в JPEG, логично предположить, что дело в альфа-канале. Пишут, что предварительная закраска фоновым цветом перед копированием улучшает итоговую картинку.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2570015/272885

Comment: Спасибо, позже попробую

Comment: может это у меня с сервером проблемы, не моглы бы Вы у себя проверить?

Comment: Нет не мог бы. Вы попробовали предложенное решение?

Comment: Пробовал, изображение становится чуть ли не белым совсем

Comment: Кстати, локалько загрузить файл не получается `imagecreatefromwebp('/pic.webp');`

Comment: Значит реально там в PNG прозрачность. А вы хотите конвертировать его в JPEG, который прозрачность не поддерживает ни в каком виде. При автоматической обработке какие-то картинки будут получаться близко к оригиналу, какие-то нет. Считаю, что без ручной обработки в графическом редакторе ваша задача не имеет нормального решения.

Comment: в png таже фигня